# Can a helicopter fly without a tail rotor?

Tags: aircraft-design, helicopter, tail-rotor

Just wondering if a helicopter can fly without a tail rotor?

Comment: if they are built not to have it, [yes](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8642/1467); if they lose it during flight, not so much.

Comment: Research NOTAR.

Comment: look for helicopter crashes on youtube, several of them involve tail rotor loss.