# Where can I find more details about how ornithopters work?

Tags: helicopter, ornithopters

I learnt about the special helicopter-ornithopter which was put forward by Delft University. Its principle is different from a common helicopter and it doesn't need a tail rotor. But there is very little information about it on the Internet. I sincerely hope that someone can give more details about it, or tell me where to find them.

It operates like this:

[image]

Comment: What details do you want? At present this question potentially suffers from being "Too broad".

Comment: In my answer [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8642/how-can-a-helicopter-be-designed-without-a-tail-rotor/16963#16963) you can find more information, and also a link to a thesis about the topic.

Comment: I edited your question a little but I'm not sure if you're asking about ornithopters in general, or the Delft one specifically? Also, I don't know what you meant by "scull". I guessed you mean "tail rotor" but I may be completely wrong so please edit again to correct it if you want.